# Convert HTML to PDF and then send email from a portlet

Tags: email, pdf, liferay, portlet, email-attachments

I have designed a portlet that has HTML form so after processing the form the value is displayed. Everything is designed and calculated in a JSP page.

Now I need a way to convert the displayed result in a PDF file and email it to the user.

I am using 6.1 version of Liferay bundled with Tomcat 7.0.

Can somebody suggest me how to do it?

Comment: to generate pdf you can check below link as reference
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Generate+PDF+File+in+Portlet
for sending email you can use mailServiceUtil.

Comment: @lucky Why don't you write your comment as an answer. May be give some code to call methods from `MailServiceUtil`.

Comment: @lucky Yes I have seen that reference you mentioned but How to call that I was stuck with that. If you can give me code snippet for version 6.1 then it will be easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, "title of the content ", template, true);
```

MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(message);

assuming you know how to configure from,to address and also template which will be a body of the mail.If not then please reply.